# Creating a drop shadow on one side of a shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, android

I am trying to recreate this effect (see photo) from the HipMunk Android app and I am having some issues as the shadow is coming out other sides on the shape. I just want the shadow out of the right side. Let me know. Thanks!

[image: shadow effect]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shadow on only one side is merely a gradient. You can create one easily by having a rectangle (3px wide, 0%fill) for the area and a gradient overlay in layer styles.

Answer (score 1):

What method are you using to create it? Your example only has a 3 pixel fade/shadow, so you could probably just fake it, but if you want the general method to create dropshadows...

In the effects pop-up (from the little fx icon at the bottom of the layers palette), if you choose dropshadow, it will take you to this:

[image]

Set the angle to 180 (horizontal) as shown.

Comment: That method does not work for me because the drop shadow will still fade out of the other sides of the shape and not just the right side. I ended up just making a 1x10 shape, made the drop shadow I wanted and then right clicked the "fx", clicked create a new layer and then just marquee deleted the shadow I didn't want.